# how to center-bottom align a down arrow?

Tags: jquery, html, css, alignment

I place a down arrow in my [web page](http://120.25.156.72/),but it does not correctly center align.

this is the css of the arrow:

```
.arrow-test{

    position: absolute;
    bottom: 40px;


    border: 80px dashed transparent;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-style: solid;

}
```

and this is an instance of the arrow:

```
<div class="section " id="section0">
    <h1>音乐学习的路是孤独的<br /></h1>  
    <span class="arrow-test"></span>
</div>
```

and a [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSMfV.jpg)

Comment: add this to `arrow-test` class `left: 50%; margin-left: -80px;` it will align to the center

Comment: it works! thanks a lot !

Comment: Was happy to help you :)

Answer (score 0):

Please reduce the margin to 0 of your bottom margin command and also change the color of your arrow from white to black to improve its visuality.